# Angular app login to cognito using PKCE then call my API

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an existing angular app that uses angular-oauth2-oidc to connect to a locally hosted identity server.
I have stripped out the angular-oauth2-oidc components and implemented a connection to AWS Cognito (using Amplify) to let users login.
The app client settings in the AWS Userpool have been set to authorization code grant.

I can login to my application, but my api isn't authorised to run.
It's taken me a month to get this far and I'm still not sure what I'm doing.

What I want to do is login to Cognito using PKCE and be able to call my api endpoints.

I can't find any examples to do what I want to do. Surely this is a common scenario. Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how to do this? An example?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the Authorization Code grant type and a hosted UI for signing in with your OIDC provider.
Although it's not clearly stated in the docs, Amplify will automatically use PKCE if the Cognito User Pool client does *not* contain a `secret` (as is the case with  SPA apps).

If you inspect your network requests, you should see a `grant_type=authorization_code` along with `code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE` and `code_verifier=CODE_VERIFIER` uri params when hitting the token endpoint